# Entity Framework One-Many Relationship on Same Entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to define Organizational chart schema in Entity Framework.

PersonelJob Entity model is:

```
public class PersonelJob : BaseEntity
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int64? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonelJob Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonelJob> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see each job could be a job parent and have some job children.

How could map this entity to Database, with Fulent Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `OnModelCreating` method on your context and add this configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonelJob>()
            .HasOptional(pj => pj.Parent)
            .WithMany(pj=>pj.Childs)
            .HasForeignKey(pj => pj.ParentId);
```